# How to accept revision from a diff file?

Tags: git, version-control

For one project I used Latex and typed up the report, and now my professor sent me a "revision.diff" file that shows all the difference she made in my "report.tex" file. I am wondering if there is a way I can accept the changes in the diff file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're on a unix machine of some sort (that is, a Linux, or a Mac).

The standard way to use diffs is with the `patch` program (`git` uses a closely related format, which is why you can potentially use `git`, but `patch` will almost certainly be present your machine, and is more straightforward).

First, make sure you're starting with exactly the same version of your .tex file that your professor received.

Then

```
% patch <revision.diff
```

...is the short answer.

Unfortunately, there's no *completely* standard way to create patches, not least because there are several more-or-less 'standard' ways to format diffs.  So there are some potential complications.

If the patch file starts looking something like this

```
2c2
< Blah blah
---
> Blah blah wibble.
```

or this:

```
--- report.tex  2012-04-30 21:05:51.000000000 +0100
+++ report-modified.tex 2012-04-30 21:06:08.000000000 +0100
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 \documentclass{article}
-Blah blah
+Blah blah wibble.
```

...then the above will^Wshould work.

If it starts off looking like this:

```
--- a/report.tex    2012-04-30 21:05:51.000000000 +0100
+++ b/report.tex    2012-04-30 21:06:08.000000000 +0100
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 \documentclass{article}
-Blah blah
+Blah blah wibble.
```

(note the `a/` and `b/` at the top), then you'll have to use

```
% patch -p1 <revision.diff
```

The `-p1` removes `1` 'level' of slashes from the file names mentioned at the top of the file.

That's basically it.  See patch(1) (that is, the manpage for the patch command) for more discussion.  In particular, anyone sending patches this way should read and digest the 'notes for patch senders' towards the bottom of the patch manpage.

If you're starting with a *slightly* different version of your `report.tex` than the one you sent your professor (moral of this part of the story, use a version control system, and tag or keep notes of the version you sent off), then the patch command will report errors, and do something like create a file called `report.tex.rej` in the same directory.  This should let you piece together the relevant changes and apply them by hand.

Comment: Hang on.  You've tagged your question with 'git', but your question doesn't mention git at all.  Are you using actually using git?  In which case the git documentation is presumably your friend (ah, I see the problem: in my experience the git documentation is nobody's friend...)

Answer (score 3):

Is it a standard unified diff-formatted file? If so, use `git apply revision.diff` to apply the patch.